# Is Java "File" and "Files" only meant for local system?

Tags: java, io

What is the IO class that can handle remote file path in another machine?

Comment: Just try it. See if it does.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Answer (score 0):

A File class represents a binary file. With the line

```
File f = new file(path)
```

You access at least a binary on your local filesystem or on a network filesystem, with

```
path = "\\\\192.168.1.50\\home\\hello.txt";
```

And I think that's all. According to the official documentation of Java 7 :

> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent pathname strings to name files and directories. This class presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames. An abstract pathname has two components:
>
> An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and
>
> A sequence of zero or more string names.

Source : [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)